# NetLogo - How to set turtle color from array

Tags: netlogo

How can I set a turtle's color from an array?

Here's my code but it doesn't work:

```
let colors array:from-list ["red" "yellow" "blue" "pink"]
set index random 3
let c array:item colors index
set color array:item colors index
```

Which leads to this error:

```
can't set flower variable COLOR to non-number blue error while flower 101 running SET
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NetLogo color, the names of the 14 main colors, plus black and white are defined as constants, so no quotes are required. Also, since they are constants, they are treated like literal values, so you can use them in the bracketed list notation, otherwise, you'd need to use the (list . . . ) reporter to create that list.

Also, your use of an array may be more complicated than needed.

You can write:

```
let colors [ red green blue yellow ]
set index random 3
let c item colors index
set color c
```

As an extra bonus, you can use the one-of primitive to do all the above:

```
set color one-of [ red green blue yellow ]
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is the correct one, but as an aside, note that the [`read-from-string`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#read-from-string) function will interpret a basic NetLogo color name as a color value:

```
observer> show read-from-string "red"
observer: 15
```

Also useful to know about is the [`base-colors`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#base-colors) built-in function that reports an array of the 14 basic NetLogo colors as numeric values, allowing you to do things such as:

```
ask turtles [ set color one-of base-colors ]
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about "base-colors"... I hope it's new in NetLogo 5, and not something I've been missing for years! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try setting your color names to number values, according to [this site](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#colors)